# Unable to add firebase to react app with "npm install firebase"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

I am trying to add firebase to my react app.But when I type npm install firebase I get strange error like:
Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '*Error message* '. *Error message* is different every time i run npm install firebase.I have looked this questions:

1. [Firebase npm install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698166/firebase-npm-install-error)
2. [Unable to do "npm install --save firebase"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687891/unable-to-do-npm-install-save-firebase)
3. [Firebase - Failing to install firebase using npm but yarn works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882224/firebase-failing-to-install-firebase-using-npm-but-yarn-works)
   I have tried **npm cache clean --force**,and after **npm update** ,but that didn't work.Also I have tried downgrading npm,but that either did not work.Also I have tried uninstalling node,and installing again ,but that did not help either.Thanks in advance

---

**npm version 6.13.7**

---

**node version v12.19.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like npm cache was corrupted ,but as  npm cache clean --force did not work,deleting _cacache  directory in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache solved my problem.After that npm install worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

How about just to be sure remove `package-lock.json` and delete node_modules folder with `rm -rf node_modules`?

And after that `npm install` again.

Good luck.